# How to test a method which is in mapStateToProps in React using Jest - Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I'm not able to increase coverage for this line `handleSave` which I'm passing as a `prop` to my component. However, I'm importing `mapStateToProps` from my container file in the test case and used `.toBeTruthy()` for validating the test case.

Here's a gist of my code

```
export const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    handleSave: title => ownProps.history.push(setTitle(title)),
  };
};
```

This is the test case that I wrote

```
it('mapStateToProps test case', () => {
  const result = mapStateToProps(state, ownProps);
  expect(result.handleSave).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Could anyone please help? What should I do to get the `handleSave` covered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is mock the `ownProps` and test out the mock function like:

```js
const mockFn = jest.fn();
const ownProps = {
 history: {
   push: mockFn
 }
}

const result = mapStateToProps(state, ownProps);

// Now call the handle save function
result.handleSave("My title");


// And then as follows:

// This will ensure that your function is calling ownProps history push method.
expect(mockFn).toBeCalled();

// To check the funciton has only been called once
expect(mockFn.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);


// This is to check if the correct argument has been passed. Be sure to pass in what your `setTitle` funciton returns 
expect(mockFn.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe("My title");
```